# How to calculate area outside bounding boxes

Tags: python, size, area, opencv

So after I've done object detection, I have a few overlapping 2d rectangles, and I want to find size of the area outside of all the rectangles I've created, which has (xyxy) coordinates on each one. How do I find size of area outside that boxes in python?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j0gj.png)

I have tried to calculate the area by adding the sizes of all the bounding boxes then the sum will be used to subtract the size from the input image. However, it is still constrained by overlapping square lengths so that the measurement is not accurate.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
from bbox import BBox2D
box1 = BBox2D([0.20212765957446807, 0.145625, 0.24822695035460993, 0.10875])
box2 = BBox2D([0.6693262411347518, 0.146875, 0.31382978723404253, 0.06875])
print(box2.height * box2.width)
print(box1.height * box1.width)
```

Try this one.
or simply u can

```
def _getArea(box):
    return (box[2] - box[0]) * (box[3] - box[1])
```

This should do the trick. Structure of Box: [xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax]

Comment: You seem to compute the area of a box, not the area _outside_ all boxes

Answer (score 0):

To find the area outside all of the boxes, you will need to do the following things.

1. Find the area of the entire image
2. Find the area of all of the rectangles (including overlapping area)
3. Find the total overlapping area
4. Subtract the total overlapping area from the total area of the rectangles
5. Subtract the rectangle area without overlap from the area of the entire image

To find the total overlapping area, you will need to loop through every rectangle on the screen and check if it is overlapping. If it is overlapping another rectangle you will need to find the corners that are overlapping each other. For example in your image, the top left and middle rectangles are overlapping. The two corners you need would be the bottom right corner of the top left rectangle and the top left corner of the middle rectangle. You can then find the area of the rectangle that is made by the overlap.

If you add a little more information in your question, I could type out a simple function that could do this but right now I don't know all the specifications.